# want to get the largest date from now on in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

Code

`Date dates = new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

output -
**292278994-08-17 12:42:55**

I want to get the largest date today onwards. How to get this using another way.292278994 this year cant save my DB I need only 4 characters for the year.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: 292278994-08-17 12:42:55  this is the output

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE is a timestamp very far in the future, so the year is apparently 292278994. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to get output like this -  2022-08-17 12:42:55 .  how to convert " 292278994 " this year format  to " 2022 ". Or any suggestions for get Date MAX value ?

Comment: To see the date of 10 seconds ago, try  `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000);`

Comment: If you want the date to be in 2022, then you should not pass a long timestamp that points to the year 292278994

Comment: by default, just `new Date()` will create the current date (using System.currentTimeMillis() as the timestamp)

Comment: Note that java.util.Date is just a wrapper around a long timestamp, nothing else. If you want to do more with time and date, then use the new java.time classes instead.

Comment: How can I get Date MAX value and MIN value in java. is there any way to get this

Comment: You just did that, by passing the Long.MAX_VALUE to the Date class, you got the largest date it can represent, which is 292278994-08-17 12:42:55

Comment: or do you want the largest date in the current year?

Comment: BTW the MIN value is obtained by passing the timestamp 0, which leads to `1970-01-01 01:00:00`

Comment: Oh 292278994 this is the MAX year from Date class. There is nothing to do for this. but how can I get the MAX Value and MIN Value in java?

Comment: Yeah I want to get largest date and minimum date in the current year .

Comment: Finally, we know what you want :-)

Comment: Ha Ha Ha... Thanks brother can you help for this :D

Comment: Set `today` to `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. Then get the earliest time of the year as `today.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear()).atStartOfDay()`. Gives `2022-01-01T00:00`. Get the latest time as `today.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear()).atTime(LocalTime.MAX)`. Gives `2022-12-31T23:59:59.999999999`. Or even beter, represent the year as the half-open interval from first time inclusive to the first time of the following year exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the boundary dates of the current year, you can use the java.time API and set the month/day values to january 1st and december 31st respectively:

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime startOfYear = now.withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1).withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
    LocalDateTime endOfYear = now.withMonth(12).withDayOfMonth(31).withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59).withNano(999999999);
    System.out.println(startOfYear);
    System.out.println(endOfYear);
```

Output:

```
2022-01-01T00:00
2022-12-31T23:59:59.999999999
```

Comment: How can I get MAX date today onwards without using  new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: @Adam As you can see, Adriaan uses `LocalDateTime`, which is a class from the `java.time` package. You should *always* use classes from this package when performing date or time related operations, rather than the obsolete `Date` and `Calendar` classes.

Comment: One could also use `LocalDateTime.MAX.with(Year.now().getValue())`.

Answer (score 0):

Epoch milliseconds are milliseconds counted from the very first moment of 1970 and they are stored as `long` in Java. That means `Long.MAX_VALUE` will get you the moment in time that is as far in the future as this representation allows. A moment that is beyond some maximum date of the current year, like some hundred million years beyond…

If you are on Java 8 or higher and try to use an `Instant` with `Long.MAX_VALUE` like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // use the greates Long as epoch millis and create an Instant from it
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    // represent the Instant as date and time of day in a specific zone
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // define the output format
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    // and print the 
    System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf));
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
+292278994-08-17 07:12:55
```

You may want to adjust the `ZoneId` to the desired one and remove the leading *plus* from the output…

But basically understand that epoch milliseconds are not years.

Comment: How does this help with OP's apparent confusion about dates?

Comment: Well, it does not help with that… It shows a different calculation resulting in the same (far) future year (earth might never reach).

Comment: 300 million years in the future... I hope they finally deprecated and removed java.util.Date by then.

Comment: This date type can't save in database because the year digits are out of range.Is there another way to get  MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE this ?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster I don't get it why it is still kept alive. Most of its methods and constructors are deprecated, but the class isn't.

Comment: @Adam find out how the database stores the values. It possibly holds a limited amount of ciphers for a year preventing you to store years laying millions of years in the future?

Comment: Sorry for my Bad !

Comment: @Adam which *bad* exactly? Which maximum and minimum *dates* do you really want?

Comment: I want to get largest date and minimum date in the current year . help me for that ?

Comment: @deHaar I guess it is used in so many existing applications that removing it would break too much.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster yes, I think so, too... Would perfectly explain why there is `Date.from(Instant)` and the reverse method.